# Generating CA, KEY and CERT keys

Tags: node.js, openssl

I inherited this bit of code:

```
import https from 'https';
// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./certs/ca.pem')
}, app);
```

The certs directory is on the `.gitignore` and there is no documentation on how to generate these `.pem` files. I have looked into openssl but none of the examples I have seem require a passphrase.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? There are a lot of examples how to use your own CA to generate a self-signed cert. Other examples explain how to use a cert signed by a CA on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate key and crt file by using this command :

> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout **server.key** -out
>   **server.csr**